# how to select a specific word using xpath javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath

I can select a element that containing a specific word,

```
//p[@class="class"][contains(text(),"disease")]
```

But I wanna select the word alone using xpath.,

Comment: XPath selects nodes, not words.

Comment: Once you get the node, you can select the word yourself

Comment: Can you share HTML sample and required output for the same?

Comment: @Andersson htmlCode `<p id="something">We propose a Bayesian scheme for BCV that accommodates the influence of context on incentive value. BCV focuses on scenarios where incentive value depends on contextual information provided before options or rewards are presented, and  where reward is defined by a single attribute <p>`  from the above p i wanna select a word ex **accommodates** for testing purpose

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you please give an example ?

Comment: @JLRishe yes Rishe, but , using xpath (contains) we can check whether the word in that element or not, means it matches the word in the element, using the same method can't we select a word ?

Comment: @SathiyaSeelanD ... no - look up documentation on "selected text" in a browser

Comment: @JaromandaX , little confusing Jaromanda Can we select word only using xpath in single line of code?

Comment: no - already told you that

Comment: @SathiyaSeelanD Please clarify what you actually trying to achieve. It sounds like you're probably going about this the wrong way. See: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JLRishe, wanna select a specific word from a <p> and trigger click event on that for testing purpose

Comment: Ok, so this problem has very little to do with XPath and a lot to do with clicking a specific word on a page.

Comment: @JLRishe, Yes Exactly ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You can.

If you stretch what you mean by *selection* to include values returned by XPath functions against actually selected nodes, you can use string functions to extract a word from the string value of a node.

For example, for this XML,

```
<a>Label: WORD</a>
```

this XPath,

```
substring-after(/a,"Label: ")
```

will return

```
WORD
```

as requested.

Comment: As clarified by OP, the objective is to be able to initiate a click event on a specific word, so `substring-after()` isn't much help with that.

Comment: @JLRishe: Agreed. I see that later OP comment, and I see that you correctly predicted a XY Problem.  I'm more answering for future readers looking for an answer to *how to select a specific word using xpath javascript* than for OP at this point.

Answer (score 0):

## You can't.

[XPath is for traversing the XML-based documents.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) XML would consider the text content as one entity and XPath won't distinguish among the words it contains.

Comment: Got it @Martin, still it checks for whether the word in that element or not (contains), but why it cannot select the word alone? can you explain me please?